# RichTextBox annoying cursor changes

Tags: vb.net, cursor, richtextbox

First of all, my problem is about the cursor, and not the caret.

-When I'm just hovering the RichTextBox, no movement, cursor is default.

-Whenever I'm moving over a character in the RichTextBox, the cursor changes from Arrow to IBeam.

-And when it comes to simply move (over space) in the RichTextBox, the cursor is changed to a symmetric one. It acts the same when clicking (right or left, doesn't matter)

How can I get rid of it ? I forced RichTextBox.Cursor to Arrow, I tried to play with RichTextBox.MouseHover event, but unfortunately nothing worked.

Thanks

Comment: No, it doesn't "blink like crazy".  The IBeam indicates to the user that he can place the caret by clicking and can enter text.  Overriding the RichTextBox.Cursor property certainly works, you left no hint whatsoever why it does not.  Given the "it blinks" complaint, you are probably doing something like assigning the Cursor.Current property in your code.  Don't do that.

Comment: I didn't change the Cursor.Current. Actually I don't want the cursor to change to IBeam.The RichTextBox is ReadOnly, then there's no reason to click text to place the caret. Btw, overriding RichTextBox.Cursor only works when you're not over a char, then it doesn't help me at all.

Comment: Why downvote ? Anyway, I edited my question to be more specific. Wondering about recording and put the record on Youtube if it's not against SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Mouse_Move** Event of RichTextBox
and set RichTextBox Cursor property to *Arrow*

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help... I already tried this with MouseHover, didn't work either.